# How to securely handle the Slack's API token in using swift on Heroku?

Tags: swift, heroku, slack

I've been following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@pvzig/building-slack-bots-in-swift-b99e243e444c) on how to build a bot using SlackKit and deploy it using Heroku.
Got everything to work but, except for the fact that I've yet to include the Slack's API token for the bot.

I'm not sure how to "safely" do this—is there a way to securely add the token in Heroku and let the Swift code retrieve it from there and afterwards add it to the bot?

From reading a bit I *think* that I need to use config variables on Heroku? If so; how do I retrieve them from within the Swift code?

If not—what should I look at then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good approach is to store the Slack API token as Heroko [config var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

You can then access them in your code as normal environment variable.

Comment: This seems like the most likely way to go after all. Thanks!